# Can't seem to rejectChanges() on an entity where setDeleted() was called

Tags: breeze

I'm using Breeze version 1.5.5 and Knockout 3.4.0 in a SPA.  I have a function I created to remove an entity from an array of entities.  I'm trying to implement an undo using rejectChanges() but the observableArray is not reverting.  When I call manager.getEntities() I see that the EntityState is set to 'unchanged'.  I'm simplified the function to an inane example:

```
var removeVehicle = function(data) {
    data.entityAspect.setDeleted();
    data.entityAspect.rejectChanges();
};
```

This function does not undelete the entity.  However when I modify the function to just make a text change it undoes the change without issue.

```
var removeVehicle = function(data) {
    data.model('test');
    data.entityAspect.rejectChanges();
};
```

I'd like to be able to undo the deletion but I'm not sure where to start.  I've also tried adding an entity beforehand and rejectChanges does indeed remove it.

EDIT: (2016-03-09) The 'parent' of this entity is an object loaded all at once when the page is activated (Durandal). I'm not sure if it's relevant but apparently Breeze has some trouble with complex objects.

EDIT: (2016-03-11) I forked the breeze.js.samples project and made similar changes to the Todo-Knockout-Require project therein ([Breeze Fork for SO35852344](https://github.com/Maleki/breeze.js.samples/tree/SO35852344).)  I still have the same issue.  The exact location of the code in question is the removeItem function in the viewModel.js file.

Comment: What was the state of the entity before calling setDeleted()?

Comment: The status was Unchanged.